# Render a consumed API on Django to React Front-end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, api

I consumed an API on Django with no Model. It displays the API result in JSON properly on a django HTML page without react:

[image: The reponse when you follow the actual url]

Now, how to render it on react frontend alongside other react component.

This is the code in Dashboard.JS

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Wallet from '../wallet/Wallet';
import withWalletLoading from '../wallet/WithWalletLoading';
import '../../App.css';
import DashboardAPI from './DashboardAPI'
import Pricing from '../Pricing'

function Dashboard() {
  
  const WalletLoading = withWalletLoading(Wallet);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    ngn_balance: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setAppState({ loading: true });
    const apiUrl = 'wallet/ngn/?format=json';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((ngn_balance) => {
        setAppState({ loading: false, ngn_balance: ngn_balance });
      });
  }, [setAppState]);

  return (
    <>
    <WalletLoading isLoading={appState.loading} ngn_balance={appState.ngn_balance} />
     <Pricing />
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Even when I use the complete url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/wallet/ngn/?format=json.
**NB** I do get status code 200 on the commandline whenever i visit the react page..
The react page where the code is being called will show properly, then when the API call loads on the page goes blank, wihout showing the API result on the react page, even before and after going blank
Just ' "/wallet/ngn" ' 200 on the commandline

wallet.js code

```
import React from 'react';

const Wallet = (props) => {
  const { ngn_balance } = props;
  if (!ngn_balance || ngn_balance.length === 0) return <p>No Data, sorry</p>;
  return (
    <ul>
      <h2 className='list-head'>Available NGN balance</h2>
      {ngn_balance.map((ngn_balances) => {
        return (
          <li>
            <span >{ngn_balances.data} </span>
            <span >{ngn_balances.status}</span>
         
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
export default Wallet;
```

Comment: Try to `console.log` the fetched result

Comment: Can I check the response format of your API?

Comment: I just added an image to my question.. youll see the response format. its in JSON format

Comment: I checked my XHR response on console, the data is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. i finally got the solution myself.
i removed the after removing .json() from the backend and frontend.

```
.then((res) => res.json()) //react
ngn_balance = response.json() //django
```

i ran the server again, then this =
`<h2 className='list-head'>Available NGN balance</h2>`
was displayed on the page.
then i changed this =

```
 <span >{ngn_balances.data} </span>
 <span >{ngn_balances.status}</span>
```

to this =

```
<span >{ngn_balances} </span>
```

and it displaced.